# How to understand the internal structure for composite fermion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions

There exists a concept of "composite fermion" when refer to heavy fermion system, which means spin-flip and conducting electron can be combined together to form a new "composite fermion".

In details, interaction between local moment fermion $f$ and conducting fermion $c$ can be decomposed into following form under the mean-field level:
$$J S_{\alpha \beta}(j) c_{j \beta}^{\dagger} c_{j \alpha} \longrightarrow \bar{V} f_{j \alpha}^{\dagger} c_{j \alpha}+V c_{j \alpha}^{\dagger} \mathrm{f}_{j \alpha}$$
the composite combination of spin and conduction electron are contracted into a single Fermi ﬁeld:
$$J \overbrace{S_{\alpha \beta}(j) c_{j \beta}^{\dagger}}=J f_{j \alpha}^{\dagger} \overbrace{f_{j \beta }^{\dagger}c_{j\beta}}\rightarrow V f_{j \alpha}^{\dagger}$$
where now $V$ is just the anomalous Green function:
$$V=G_{cf}=-J\left\langle c_{j \beta}^{\dagger} f_{j \beta}\right\rangle$$
Then, we can approximately calculate this anomalous Green function $g(\tau)=-G_{cf}(\tau)$, and find that:
$$g(\tau) \sim\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{ \ln \tau} & {\tau \ll 1} \\ {\frac{1}{\tau}} & {\tau \gg1}\end{array}\right.$$
and author concludes that The short-time logarithimic correlations between the spin-ﬂip and electron ($τ \ll 1$ ) represent the weak-coupling interior of the composite fermion, whereas the long-time power law correlations reﬂect the development of the Fermi liquid correlations at long times.

## My question

I am confused of the last augments, i.e. I can not understand the relation between this Green function and internal structure of composite particle. Furthermore, I even cannot understand the physical meaning of "internal structure" for composite fermion here. Could anyone help me, or gives some reference?

*In Summary, this question can be concluded as: According to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/455879/208742), from the view of effective field theory, two boson/fermmion particles form a composite particle, the resulting state has internal structure. But I cannot know how to obtain and analyze  internal structure?* Reference about it is welcome!

### Reference

- Ch.17.8, Piers Coleman, *Introduction to Many-Body Physics*
- Piers Coleman, *Heavy fermions: Electrons at the Edge of Magnetism*