# Will more than one composite boson can stay in the same energy state if constituent fermions has moderate entanglement?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, fermions, many-body, bosons

Let say we consider two distinguishable fermions(bi-fermions) in compact form. The case when both fermions are existing as free fermions, they will obey Pauli exclusion principle. In other case if pair of fermions are maximally entangled and making composite boson similar to pure boson. More than one composite boson can stay in same energy state. But what about the case when pair of fermions is making a composite boson but the properties of this composite boson are deviating from pure boson. And composite boson has less degree of compositeness. Will fermions obey pauli exclusion principle or not? Will more than one composite boson can stay in the same energy state or not in this case?

Comment: Distinguishable particles are not subject to Pauli exclusion.

Comment: In single composite boson we are taking distinguishable fermions. But if we consider N composite bosons they are identical. And fermions of two composite bosons will oppose each other because of pauli exclusion principle , in case when composite boson is deviating from pure boson @probably_someone

Comment: My comment was in relation to this: "The case when both fermions are existing as free fermions, they will obey Pauli exclusion principle."

Comment: Ya, but what in case when we have N identical composite bosons but these composite bosons has less compositeness compare to pure bosons. @probably_someone

Comment: First of all, what does it mean to have "less compositeness"? Also, related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45644/can-bosons-that-are-composed-of-several-fermions-occupy-the-same-state

Comment: Less compositeness means that properties of composite boson is deviating from pure boson because of its internal structure. @probably_someone

Comment: Can you give an example of which properties you're referring to when you say "the properties of this composite boson are deviating from pure boson"?

Comment: Like in case of pure bosons $[ c, c^{\dagger} ]=1$ where c and c^{\dagger} are annihilation and creation operators. But in case of composite boson $[ c, c^a[\dagger} ] = 1 + D , where this D is related to onstituent fermions of which composite boson is made up of . @probably_someone

Comment: I encourage you to read the answer in the link I posted.

Comment: Ya i am reading that, thanks, do you have some other property in your mind about composite boson that can be different than pure boson ? @probably_someone