# How can multiple fermions combine to form a boson?

Tags: quantum-spin, standard-model, fermions, bosons

I understand that composite particles with integer spin form a boson. For example a helium nucleus is a boson because it has 2 protons and 2 neutrons.

If all of the components on their own are fermions, which mean they can not occupy the same space, how can combining them allow them to now occupy the same space?

I guess my question is: Is there an "intuitive" explanation for this behavior, or is the answer just the integer spin always equals boson?

Comment: *"how can combining them allow them to now occupy the same space"* - are composite bosons pointlike particles?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [Can bosons that are composed of several fermions occupy the same state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45644/140996)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pauli exclusion principle applies to  the constituent fermions of the composite bosons. For example, many atoms of helium can be in the same lowest energy state forming a superfluid. However, they cannot be squeezed to a zero volume, because the Pauli exclusion principle holds for protons and neutrons, as well as for their constituent quarks.

Comment: Ok, so only elementary particles that are bosons do not follow the Pauli exclusion formula?

Comment: @jminardi Correct, elementary bosons (e.g. photons) do not follow the Pauli exclusion principle.